# Make closing questions proportional to participation levels

Tags: feature-request

When a question has been found valuable by dozens if not hundreds of community members who have answered, commented, and voted, this should not be able to be overridden by 5 empowered users. The arbitrary views of literally 1 hand full of individuals should not override many multiples more.

Comment: That a question is popular is in no way an indication that the question is on topic for the site.  Popularity in no way indicates on-topicness.

Comment: If it's popular AND not relevant it should be popular for empowered users to take action on a scale much more substantive than a spam posting or nonsensical posting.

Comment: It takes only a set of another five empowered users to reopen the question.

Comment: There's a lot of spam and nonsensical posting that can get pretty popular.

Comment: @Servy that would imply that's valued content and both understood and not spam.

Comment: When it is closed it is not deleted. It only takes an hand full of empowered users to reopen questions.

Comment: @ChrisMarisic It implies none of those things.  It implies only that it's popular.  Spam can be popular, nonsense can be popular, and content without value can be popular.

Answer (score 11):

Just because something's popular doesn't make it on topic for a site.

We've seen this time and time again.

Stack Overflow (and by extension Stack Exchange) should not be seen as a repository for **all** knowledge on a subject. They are question and answer sites with restricted scope.